# The second stable homotopy group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences

I am interested in the low-degree stable homotopy group $\pi_2^{s}(X)$ of a path-connected space $X$. Using the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, we have the short exact sequence $0\to H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)\to \pi_2^{s}(X)\to H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})\to 0$.

**Question:** Does it always split?

---

**Edit:** I've been working on a solution to my question, and I believe I've made progress. However, I've hit a roadblock in the proof and I'm hoping for some assistance. I will award the best answer to whoever can help me finish my proof or provide insight into my original question.

I think my exact sequence splits canonically! My idea is to show the following dual exact sequence splits canonically:
$$
0\to H^2(X,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\pi_2^s(X),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\stackrel{h}{\to} H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)\to 0,
$$
where I use the canonical isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\cong H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$.
Next, I define $\phi$ as the generator of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\pi^s_2(K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2$. For each $f\in H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong[X,K(\mathbb{Z}/2,1)]$, I consider the pullback $f^*\phi\in\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\pi^s_2(X),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. This defines a map $[\phi]:H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)\mapsto\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\pi^s_2(X),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ that sends $f$ to $f^*\phi$.

I'm tempted to believe that $[\phi]$ is a homomorphism and $[\phi]\circ h=\mathrm{id}_{H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)}$, but I cannot come up with a proof. If you have any insights into this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

---

**Edit2** I’m really happy to see some of you enjoyed this question! Then what’s left for myself is to figure out how my argument fails, especially the naturality part.

Comment: I think it's better to post a question to just one of mathoverflow and math.stackexchange, not to both at the same time: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661599/the-second-stable-homotopy-group.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you for the suggestion. Let me stick to mathoverflow and remove that question.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Hello! I decided to remove the same question on math.stackexchange, so let me address your question here. Differentials of the type $H_2(X,\pi^s_i)\to H_0(X,\pi^s_{i+1})$ are trivial due to the canonical splitting $\mathbb{S}_{\bullet}(X)=\pi^s_{\bullet}\oplus\pi^s_{\bullet}(X)$. The other differential $H_3(X,\pi^s_0)\to H_1(X,\pi^s_1)$ is the composition of the mod-2 reduction and the dual of $\mathrm{Sq}^2$, which is trivial due to the dimensional reason.

Comment: Here's a small observation: For a $1$-connective spectrum, the corresponding sequence does not necessarily split, as can be seen by attaching a $3$-cell to $\mathbb{S}^1\oplus \mathbb{S}^2$ along $(\eta,2)$. So if this holds for spaces, it is an unstable phenomenon, so the Adams spectral sequence is probably not helpful (on its own).

Comment: @AchimKrause Thanks! Indeed, if my argument in the updated version of my question is correct, it doesn't work for spectrum $X$.

Comment: @AchimKrause what happens if you attach a 3-cell to $\Omega S^2 \wedge S^2$ by $(h, 2)$ where "h" is the adjoint of the hopf map. This is an unstable analog of what you suggest. Does it split in this case?

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries, I presume your $\wedge$ is a $\vee$. Unfortunately, the suspension of $h$ splits, using the James splitting and the observation that the Hopf invariant of $\eta$ is $1$. So the suspension spectrum of the cofiber of $S^2\to \Omega S^2\vee S^2$ just splits into a bunch of spheres.

Comment: I do not think that your proposed splitting map can be a homomorphism, because there cannot be a natural splitting. If there were, then the map $A\hat{\otimes }A\to A\wedge A$ in Fernando Muro's answer would have a natural right inverse $s$ that is a homomorphism. But by universal example one can work out what the natural maps $t:A\hat A\to A\hat{\otimes }A$ are, and none of them does the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I love this question! I've enjoyed thinking of it. Below, I show why the sequence splits always.

Let $X\to Y=K(H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2),1)$ be the map inducing the identity in $H_1(-,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. By naturality, we have have a commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
0&\to& H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)&\to& \pi_2^{st}(X)&\to&H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})&\to&0
\\
\downarrow&&\cong\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\\
0&\to& H_1(Y,\mathbb{Z}/2)&\to& \pi_2^{st}(Y)&\to&H_2(Y,\mathbb{Z})&\to&0
\end{array}
$$
Hence, if the bottom sequence splits, the upper one too.

Let $A=H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. We have another commutative diagram where all vertical maps are isomorphisms:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
0&\to& A\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2&\to& A\hat{\otimes} A&\to&A\wedge A&\to&0\\
\downarrow&&\cong\downarrow&&\cong\downarrow&&\cong\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\\
0&\to& H_1(Y,\mathbb{Z}/2)&\to& \pi_2^{st}(Y)&\to&H_2(Y,\mathbb{Z})&\to&0
\end{array}
$$
Here $A\hat{\otimes}A$ and $A\wedge A$ are the quotients of $A\otimes A$ by the relations $a\otimes b+b\otimes a=0$, $a,b\in A$, in the first case, and $a\otimes a=0$, $a\in A$, in the second case. The morphism $A\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\to A\hat{\otimes} A$ is given by $a\otimes 1\mapsto [a\otimes a]$. This actually holds for any $Y=K(A,1)$ with $A$ abelian. See:

Brown, Ronald; Loday, Jean-Louis Van Kampen theorems for diagrams of spaces. With an appendix by M. Zisman. Topology 26 (1987), no. 3, 311–335. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938387900048?via%3Dihub

The top sequence in the second commutative diagram splits because $A=H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$, so it is a short exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-vector spaces.

We can also proceed without using the Brown-Loday paper, as hinted below by Tom Goodwillie in a comment. It suffices to show that $\pi_2^{st}(Y)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-vector space. We have $\pi_2^{st}(Y)=\pi_4(\Sigma^2Y)$ since $Y$ is connected. The space $Y$ is a product of copies of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$. By the splitting of the suspension of a product, $\Sigma^2 Y$ is a wedge of copies of $\Sigma^2(\mathbb{R}P^\infty\wedge\stackrel{n}\cdots\wedge\mathbb{R}P^\infty)$. The latter space is $4$-connected for $n>2$, hence $\pi_2^{st}(Y)$ is a direct sum of copies of $\pi_4\Sigma^2\mathbb{R}P^\infty=\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\pi_4\Sigma^2(\mathbb{R}P^\infty\wedge\mathbb{R}P^\infty)=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

**P.S.** A previous version of this answer contained a partial proof. The argument was similar, but this final version is even simpler.

Comment: After your edition, some crucial information that was in original version is missing so that it is impossible to follow the proof...

Comment: @user43326 what do you find missing? I can bring it back since old versions are kept.

Comment: What is your $A$?

Comment: @DaveBenson thx! Fixed.

Comment: I enjoyed the question, too, and the answer. Let me point out a further simplification: you do not need the Brown-Loday reference if you observe that $\pi_2^S(K(A,1))$ is a $\mathbb Z/2$-vector space whenever $A$ is a $\mathbb Z/2$-vector space.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie you're right. In a previous version I was using $K(H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}),1)$ instead of $K(H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2),1)$ so I needed the general computation but when reducing mod 2 it's unnecessary.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie I hope you don't mind me adding a paragraph following your hint.

Comment: Note that the splitting isn't natural, even when restricted to spaces $X$ of the form $K(A,1)$ with $A$ a $\mathbb Z/2$ vector space.

Comment: @Fernando Muro of course, please do.